# Java Generics vs. non-generic constructors

Tags: java, oop, generics

Why would anybody want to use a generic class:

```
Animal<T> (T t) {}
```

instead of a non-generic class with a constructor that takes specific arguments. In this case:

```
Animal(String s) {}
```

Should I choose one or the other based on what I find more convenient?

Comment: Are you asking about generic constructors or about constructors in generic classes?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Both. Why would anybody ever choose to use generic something over non-generic?

Comment: Read the first sentence of the tutorial [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/why.html).

Comment: Read the generics tutorial. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/. Isn't it cool to be able to have list of strings and list of Integers, instead of just lists, without any type safety?

Comment: @JBNizet I feel that this question should be closed, but I can't match it to any of the new close reasons. Do you have an opinion on the issue; is it worth trying to drag back up on meta?

Comment: @chrylis "Unclear what you're asking" fits, unless the OP is asking "What is the purpose of Generics" in which case it's "Too Broad".

Comment: No specific opinion. My personal opinion is that we should be able to close questions which have their answer in an official documentation (like the javadoc or the official Oracle Java tutorial), but well, half of the questions could be closed. I like answering questions, but the moderation side of SO is not my thing.

Comment: @BrianRoach I'm mostly talking about the questions that would have fallen under "minimal understanding", i.e., LMGTFY. I don't mind reasonable newbie questions, but there's no way to "close duplicate from RTFJavadoc".

Comment: @chrylis Yeah, agreed. Only thing you can do is downvote appropriately (RTFM falls under "research effort" IMHO) and move on these days. It's a shame, really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generics offers type safety at compile time, which could avoid serious runtime errors like ClassCastExceptions.

Comment: This is really a comment and not an answer, but it is exactly right.

Comment: Thanks :D. I thought I should give a simple to the point explanation.